# Bootstrap v3.3.5: Activating a Tab and Tab Pane from Button on the Same Page

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I need to be able to activate a tab and tab pane from a button from within another tab pane. I don't know much about JS scripting so I'm hoping someone can help.  My code is as follows:

```
    <div class='container-fluid'>
      <ul class='nav nav-tabs'>
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home-tab">Home</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Migration-tab">Migration Info</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#howTo-tab">Learning Center</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#aboutUs-tab">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#contactUs-tab">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
   <div class='tab-content'>
<div id='home-tab' class='tab-pane fade in active'>
    <div class="panel panel-default" style="padding:3px;">
        <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color: #6600CC; ">
            <h3 style="font-family:Calibri; font-weight:bold; color:white; line-height:0; margin-top:5px; margin-bottom:5px;">
            Migration</h3>      
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <p>The SharePoint Migration is a large scale 
            effort being led by NPPD to update our current 
            SharePoint platform to the next level. This 
            effort will take several months. To access more 
            information click on the Migration Tab.</p>
            <a href="#Migration-tab" class="btn btn-default pull-right" role="button" data-toggle="tab">
            More Information</a>
        </div>      
    </div>  
</div>
<div id='Migration-tab' class='tab-pane fade'>
    Migration Info  
</div>

 </div>
 </div><!--End Main Container-->
```

The way it's suppose to work is the user click on the "Migration" button on in the Home tab pane and it's suppose to activate the Migration tab and tab pane.  But only the Migration pane gets activated.  So while the information is there the "Home" tab is still actually active.  If the user then wants to click on another tab they have to click on "Migration" then click on the tab they want.  Is there a way to get this to work so both the tab and tab pane become active?
I've been looking for weeks now and cannot find anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for the migration button in the Home tab pane click event and then use the .tab function provided by bootstrap

You may do something like this

```
$("#Migration-tab").click(function(){
   $('[data-toggle="tab"][href="#Migration-tab"]').tab('show');
})
```

i found this solution [over here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_tab.asp), you may wanna take a look.

**Note:** i didn't test your code, i used some code sample in the above link.

Comment: Sorry this still doesn't work.  It will activate the tab-pane but not the tab as well.  I think something in the code needs to change the tab's status to active.  But I'm not sure how to edit your code.  It may help if I add id's to the <li>.

Comment: good idea ! adding id's will make it more clear try it and let me know if it works